# Flask-Admin: route to models view with filter applied

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a model in Flask-Admin with filter (e.g. based on Foreign Key to other model).

I want to generate links from front-end to this model view in admin with filter value applied. I noticed that it adds `?flt0_0=` to the `url`, so that the whole address looks kinda:

`http:/.../admin/model_view_<my model>/?flt0_0=<filter value>`

Which is the best way to generate routes like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no public API for this yet. Here's a short snippet you can use for now to generate fltX_Y query string:

```
class MyView(BaseModelView):
...
    def get_filter_arg(self, filter_name, filter_op='equals'):
        filters = self._filter_groups[filter_name].filters
        position = self._filter_groups.keys().index(filter_name)

        for f in filters:
            if f['operation'] == filter_op:
                return 'flt%d_%d' % (position, f['index'])
```

Then you can call this method on a your view instance:

```
print my_view.get_filter_arg('Name', 'contains')
```

Answer (score 7):

I prefer setting `named_filter_urls=True` on my base view to get rid of these magic numbers (though you can just set it on any specific view as well):

```
class MyBaseView(BaseModelView):
    ...
    named_filter_urls = True


class MyView(MyBaseView):
    ...
    column_filters = ['name', 'country']
```

This creates URLs like: `http://.../admin/model/?flt_name_equals=foo&flt_country_contains=bar` (*)

With this, your URLs can easily be contructed using the name of the attribute you want to filter on. As a bonus, you don't need to have a view instance available - important if you want to link to a view for a different model.

*(When selecting filters from UI, Flask-Admin will insert integers into the parameter keys. I'm not sure why it does that, but they don't appear necessary for simple filtering.)

Comment: I wouldn't be sure about using it, it causes a lot of unpredictable behaviour while using multiple filters

Answer (score 7):

Flask-Admin defaults to the `flt0_0=<value>` syntax to be ["robust across translations"](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.named_filter_urls) if your app needs to support multiple languages. If you don't need to worry about translations, setting `named_filter_urls=True` is the way to go.

With `named_filter_urls=True` Flask-Admin generates filter query parameters like:

```
flt0_country_contains=<value>
```

The remaining integer after `flt` (`0` in this case) is a sort key used to control the order of the filters as they appear in the UI when you have multiple filters defined. **This number does not matter at all if you have a single filter.**

For example, in my app I have named filters turned on. If I have multiple filters **without the sort key** the filters are displayed in **the order they appear in the query string**:

```
?flt_balance_smaller_than=100&flt_balance_greater_than=5
```

Yields: [Default filter ordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr1hS.png)

**With a sort key** added to the `flt` parameters, then I can force those filters to be **displayed in a different order** (`flt1` will come before `flt2`):

```
?flt2_balance_smaller_than=100&flt1_balance_greater_than=5
```

Yields: [Forced filter ordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcsOy.png)

In practice it looks like this sort key can be **any single character**, e.g. this works too:

```
?fltB_balance_smaller_than=100&fltA_balance_greater_than=5
```

This behavior is ultimately defined in the Flask-Admin `BaseModelView._get_list_filter_args()` method here:
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1714-L1739